# Using PHP & IMAP to get emails not already grabbed

Tags: php, sql, email, imap

This is more of a question about best practices - I hope that's ok.

I am using PHP and IMAP to grab emails from a Gmail account every 30 minutes. I only want the script to grab emails from 30 minutes ago, so it will never grab the same email twice.

There is a "since" command in the search query:

```
imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "Ticket #" SINCE "'.date("Y-m-d").'"');
```

But this will only take a date and not a time.

I can technically do a loop through all emails and only grab emails that are 30 minutes away from the current time:

```
$email_time = strtotime($overview[0]->date);
$current_time = strtotime('-30 minutes');
if($email_time >= $current_time) {
    ...
}
```

I don't believe this to be a reliable solution though, because whose to say the emails aren't delayed, or what happens if the server goes down for a few minutes?

Every time the cron job executes the email script, I can store the time in the database and use that time as a reference to check all emails since. But then I need to create a brand new table, just for one field?

I'm thinking there must be a better solution....

Comment: Sorry I don't have a complete answer, but I found this topic here on SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166280/php-fetch-over-20000-imap-emails
which suggests that maybe you can do something with the UIDs. Especially the bit where it goes `04 UID FETCH 58:* UID` to fetch only the UIDs of messages after UID 58 sounds useful - if you can somehow keep track of the last UID you have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.  You should track the UIDs of the messages you download.  All new messages that arrive will have a higher UID than any previous message.  So just fetch messages with UIDs higher than you already have.

Comment: UIDs are per folder: make sure you track INBOX vs SENT separately,.